# Angular CLI installation very slow and finishes with error

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install

I have trouble installing Angular CLI. I'm currently on Linux Mint 19.

Here's what I do :

```
~$ node --version
v8.12.0
~$ npm -version
6.4.1
```

I've also tried with node v10.12.0 but the results are the same.

```
~$ npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

~$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

It takes very long. It hangs at :

```
fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule @angular/cli@6.2.5 checking installable status
```

But that changes, it hangs at different stages with every try.

When I run in a different terminal the network monitoring tool "iftop" :

```
sudo iftop -i wlp3s0
```

and filter "npmjs" (for "https://registry.npmjs.org/") by pressing l I see the entry but only a few hundred kb go back and forth.

I've also tried https -> http with the command :

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

but the result is still the same. It just hangs at different stages.

Finally it finishes with :

```
~$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...marked":"^1.0.0","bra'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/<owner>/.npm/_logs/2018-10-14T21_00_48_107Z-debug.log
```

The content of the log file is :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/opt/node/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/node/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose npm-session c5776088b57d247a
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 22ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for @angular/cli@latest fetched in 44ms
9 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 209ms
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
13 silly install loadShrinkwrap
14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 4ms
15 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
16 silly resolveWithNewModule @angular/cli@6.2.5 checking installable status
17 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fcore 39ms (from cache)
18 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2farchitect 41ms (from cache)
19 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fschematics 41ms (from cache)
20 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@schematics%2fangular 43ms (from cache)
21 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema-traverse 44ms (from cache)
22 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@schematics%2fupdate 45ms (from cache)
23 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/opn 43ms (from cache)
24 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/semver 47ms (from cache)
25 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs 49ms (from cache)
26 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/symbol-observable 51ms (from cache)
27 silly pacote version manifest for @angular-devkit/core@0.8.5 fetched in 65ms
28 silly resolveWithNewModule @angular-devkit/core@0.8.5 checking installable status
29 silly pacote version manifest for @angular-devkit/architect@0.8.5 fetched in 68ms
30 silly resolveWithNewModule @angular-devkit/architect@0.8.5 checking installable status
31 silly pacote version manifest for @angular-devkit/schematics@0.8.5 fetched in 67ms
32 silly resolveWithNewModule @angular-devkit/schematics@0.8.5 checking installable status
33 silly pacote version manifest for @schematics/angular@0.8.5 fetched in 67ms
34 silly resolveWithNewModule @schematics/angular@0.8.5 checking installable status
35 silly pacote range manifest for json-schema-traverse@^0.4.1 fetched in 67ms
36 silly resolveWithNewModule json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 checking installable status
37 silly pacote version manifest for @schematics/update@0.8.5 fetched in 67ms
38 silly resolveWithNewModule @schematics/update@0.8.5 checking installable status
39 silly pacote range manifest for opn@^5.3.0 fetched in 65ms
40 silly resolveWithNewModule opn@5.4.0 checking installable status
41 silly pacote range manifest for rxjs@~6.2.0 fetched in 68ms
42 silly resolveWithNewModule rxjs@6.2.2 checking installable status
43 silly pacote range manifest for semver@^5.1.0 fetched in 69ms
44 silly resolveWithNewModule semver@5.6.0 checking installable status
45 silly pacote range manifest for symbol-observable@^1.2.0 fetched in 69ms
46 silly resolveWithNewModule symbol-observable@1.2.0 checking installable status
47 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/yargs-parser 9ms (from cache)
48 silly pacote range manifest for yargs-parser@^10.0.0 fetched in 11ms
49 silly resolveWithNewModule yargs-parser@10.1.0 checking installable status
50 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar 6ms (from cache)
51 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ajv 7ms (from cache)
52 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map 42ms (from cache)
53 silly pacote range manifest for chokidar@^2.0.3 fetched in 46ms
54 silly resolveWithNewModule chokidar@2.0.4 checking installable status
55 silly pacote range manifest for ajv@~6.4.0 fetched in 47ms
56 silly resolveWithNewModule ajv@6.4.0 checking installable status
57 silly pacote range manifest for source-map@^0.5.6 fetched in 47ms
58 silly resolveWithNewModule source-map@0.5.7 checking installable status
59 silly pacote range manifest for json-schema-traverse@^0.3.0 fetched in 2ms
60 silly resolveWithNewModule json-schema-traverse@0.3.1 checking installable status
61 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/fast-json-stable-stringify 8ms (from cache)
62 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/fast-deep-equal 9ms (from cache)
63 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/uri-js 9ms (from cache)
64 silly pacote range manifest for fast-json-stable-stringify@^2.0.0 fetched in 11ms
65 silly resolveWithNewModule fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0 checking installable status
66 silly pacote range manifest for fast-deep-equal@^1.0.0 fetched in 12ms
67 silly resolveWithNewModule fast-deep-equal@1.1.0 checking installable status
68 silly pacote range manifest for uri-js@^3.0.2 fetched in 12ms
69 silly resolveWithNewModule uri-js@3.0.2 checking installable status
70 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/punycode 2ms (from cache)
71 silly pacote range manifest for punycode@^2.1.0 fetched in 4ms
72 silly resolveWithNewModule punycode@2.1.1 checking installable status
73 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/anymatch 20ms (from cache)
74 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/async-each 18ms (from cache)
75 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/braces 18ms (from cache)
76 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/glob-parent 17ms (from cache)
77 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/inherits 17ms (from cache)
78 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/is-binary-path 17ms (from cache)
79 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/is-glob 17ms (from cache)
80 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.debounce 16ms (from cache)
81 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-path 17ms (from cache)
82 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for braces@^2.3.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...marked":"^1.0.0","bra'
83 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/path-is-absolute 21ms (from cache)
84 silly pacote range manifest for anymatch@^2.0.0 fetched in 28ms
85 silly resolveWithNewModule anymatch@2.0.0 checking installable status
86 silly pacote range manifest for async-each@^1.0.0 fetched in 27ms
87 silly resolveWithNewModule async-each@1.0.1 checking installable status
88 silly pacote range manifest for glob-parent@^3.1.0 fetched in 26ms
89 silly resolveWithNewModule glob-parent@3.1.0 checking installable status
90 silly pacote range manifest for inherits@^2.0.1 fetched in 26ms
91 silly resolveWithNewModule inherits@2.0.3 checking installable status
92 silly pacote range manifest for is-binary-path@^1.0.0 fetched in 26ms
93 silly resolveWithNewModule is-binary-path@1.0.1 checking installable status
94 silly pacote range manifest for is-glob@^4.0.0 fetched in 27ms
95 silly resolveWithNewModule is-glob@4.0.0 checking installable status
96 silly pacote range manifest for lodash.debounce@^4.0.8 fetched in 27ms
97 silly resolveWithNewModule lodash.debounce@4.0.8 checking installable status
98 silly pacote range manifest for normalize-path@^2.1.1 fetched in 27ms
99 silly resolveWithNewModule normalize-path@2.1.1 checking installable status
100 silly pacote range manifest for path-is-absolute@^1.0.0 fetched in 30ms
101 silly resolveWithNewModule path-is-absolute@1.0.1 checking installable status
102 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/readdirp 17ms (from cache)
103 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/upath 11ms (from cache)
104 http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents 11ms (from cache)
105 silly pacote range manifest for readdirp@^2.0.0 fetched in 22ms
106 silly resolveWithNewModule readdirp@2.2.1 checking installable status
107 silly pacote range manifest for upath@^1.0.5 fetched in 16ms
108 silly resolveWithNewModule upath@1.1.0 checking installable status
109 silly pacote range manifest for fsevents@^1.2.2 fetched in 17ms
110 silly resolveWithNewModule fsevents@1.2.4 checking installable status
111 silly tarball trying https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.2.4.tgz by hash: sha512-z8H8/diyk76B7q5wg+Ud0+CqzcAF3mBBI/bA5ne5zrRUUIvNkJY//D3BqyH571KuAC4Nr7Rw7CjWX4r0y9DvNg==
112 silly extract https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.2.4.tgz extracted to /tmp/npm-8216-7cbe3717/unpack-c30ea2f4 (228ms)
113 silly addBundled read tarball
114 silly cleanup remove extracted module
115 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
116 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 882ms
117 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...marked":"^1.0.0","bra'
117 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
117 verbose stack     at parseJson (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
117 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
117 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
117 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
118 verbose cwd /home/myuser
119 verbose Linux 4.15.0-36-generic
120 verbose argv "/opt/node/bin/node" "/opt/node/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
121 verbose node v8.12.0
122 verbose npm  v6.4.1
123 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...marked":"^1.0.0","bra'
124 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My internet connection is fine, I've done speed tests, and browsing web sites is fine in general. Just to be sure I also rebooted the router / modem.

I'm not behind a firewall or a proxy.

What might be the problem ?

Any help is appreciated !

UPDATE : when I run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest --verbose
```

I get these lines in output (among others) :

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 182470ms
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 182648ms
```

That makes 3 minutes each.
So it's not me but registry.npmjs.org ??

The status site show everything is ok though : https://status.npmjs.org/ !??

UPDATE 2:

It took ~10 minutes and it always ends with a JSON parse error :

```
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 560195ms
npm verb stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^0.4.2","js-beautif'
npm verb stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
npm verb stack     at parseJson (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
npm verb stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
npm verb stack     at <anonymous>
npm verb stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying dozens of times and after many, many hours, it finally resolved from itself.

Last few installation went further and further until finally the installation of Angular completed successfully.

Note; I switched to the latest node package : v10.12.0

```
~$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/opt/node/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/opt/node/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   '@angular/cli@latest',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.4.1
npm info using node@v10.12.0
npm verb npm-session b518ace2714f8907
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 670ms
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 826ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 2ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2farchitect 253ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema-traverse 301ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/symbol-observable 386ms

... many more lines ....

npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-wsl 102ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/camelcase 95ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 84528ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 84651ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 96ms
npm verb correctMkdir /home/myuser/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb makeDirectory /home/myuser/.npm/_locks creation not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /home/myuser/.npm/_locks/staging-839dd594c5d4c44e.lock for /opt/node/lib/node_modules/.staging
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream 86ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema-traverse/-/json-schema-traverse-0.3.1.tgz 111ms

... many more lines ....


npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/atob/-/atob-2.1.2.tgz 47036ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/har-schema/-/har-schema-2.0.0.tgz 76429ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ret/-/ret-0.1.15.tgz 87815ms
npm timing action:extract Completed in 90290ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 223ms
npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 536ms
npm info lifecycle json-schema-traverse@0.3.1~preinstall: json-schema-traverse@0.3.1

... many more lines ....

npm info lifecycle kind-of@3.2.2~preinstall: kind-of@3.2.2
npm info lifecycle kind-of@4.0.0~preinstall: kind-of@4.0.0
npm timing action:preinstall Completed in 48ms
npm info linkStuff json-schema-traverse@0.3.1
npm info linkStuff ansi-regex@2.1.1
npm info linkStuff aproba@1.2.0

... many more lines ....


npm info lifecycle opn@5.4.0~postinstall: opn@5.4.0
npm info lifecycle symbol-observable@1.2.0~postinstall: symbol-observable@1.2.0
npm info lifecycle yargs-parser@10.1.0~postinstall: yargs-parser@10.1.0
npm info lifecycle @angular/cli@6.2.5~postinstall: @angular/cli@6.2.5
npm timing action:postinstall Completed in 66ms
npm verb unlock done using /home/myuser/.npm/_locks/staging-839dd594c5d4c44e.lock for /opt/node/lib/node_modules/.staging
npm timing stage:executeActions Completed in 91462ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 104ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 177168ms
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
npm verb notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64

+ @angular/cli@6.2.5
added 242 packages from 191 contributors in 177.174s
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 177486ms
npm info ok 
:~$ ng -version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.2.5
Node: 10.12.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.5
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.5
@schematics/angular          0.8.5
@schematics/update           0.8.5
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2
```

I'll leave this here in hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears that your config did not work, as NPM is still talking `https` not `http`.

Maybe try it again with quotes `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"`

Also, I've faced certain slowness issues with Android emulator that were solved by using a different DNS, like Google's DNS, `8.8.8.8`. Try that. Try also deleting your Wifi and connecting to it again if are using Wifi.

Do you have a proxy? This is the core of most NPM problems, usually on Windows but could also be on Linux. Try setting the proxy in NPM. Something like:

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm config set http-proxy "http://username:password@ip:port"
npm config set https-proxy "http://username:password@ip:port"
npm set strict-ssl false
```

[Source](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9401#issuecomment-134569585)

Answer (score 0):

If angular or angular material installation takes a long time and ends with an error, run the following command:

```
npm cache verify
```